# Given a number n and two integers p1,p2 determine if the bits in position p1 and p2 are the same or not. Positions p1,p2 and 1 based

Tags: java, c++

I've been doing some little code quizes just to catch back up on my coding after graduating but this one got my stump. Here's the question:

Given a number n and two integers p1,p2 determine if the bits in position p1 and p2 are the same or not. Positions p1,p2 and 1 based.

Example

22,3,2 would be true because it's 0001 0110 because the 2 and 3 position are the same.

I solved it one way which is to convert the decimal to binary and then into to a string and check if the bits in the positions are the same, but I feel there's an easier way to do with bit manipulation but i'm not really good with it. I was thinking if I could just shift the bits to the first position and compare them I could get the answer but then I ran into the problem when I shift them to the shift left since they just overflow.

Comment: I'm waiting for the first Java-Guy to post an answer that solves the problem via strings..

Comment: @Nils, apparently that's the way the OP did it...

Comment: Haha yeah, I did the java way which works but I'd like to do it a more efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could shift the interesting bits to the least significant position and then mask off all the other bits with `&`.

Assuming `p1` and `p2` are zero-based indexes counting from the least significant bit:

```
bool same_bits = (((n >> p1) & 1) == ((n >> p2) & 1))
```

Comment: erm, p1 and p2 are 1 indexed.. may want to fix your answer

Comment: @Nim: Since the question is tagged `homework` adjusting for one-based indexes is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: I saw your edit after I commented, makes my comment look a little silly..ah well...

Comment: Thanks this is helping me a lot. I knew I had to do masking I just didn't know how

Comment: @K.T if this answer is what you are looking for, click on the green tick to accept it and give credit to @sth.

Answer (score 1):

```
int bitPositionsSame(uint32_t n, uint32_t p1, uint32_t p2) {
        uint32_t i1 =  (n & (1 << p1)) >> p1;
        uint32_t i2 = (n & (1 << p2)) >> p2;
        return (i1 == i2);
}
```

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are one-based, and this fails for two (matching) zero bits.

Comment: Still treating `p1` and `p2` as zero-based. :)

Comment: :) that's not what I fixed :) :) :) :) :)

:)  The reader really does want a zero-index-based answer, they just don't know it because they are fresh out of school.

Comment: That's why they call me the Oracle. These comments are all smiles. I make people happy.  I hope all these different answers help you out K.T.  Just asking for a simple bit-field comparison yields many results--another great result of this question.  Wait...are we being meta-questioned?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

(((0x1 << p1) & n) == 0) == (((0x1 << p2) & n) == 0)

This will create a bit mask of 1 as the p1/p2 bit and then apply it on the number. We then check if both are zero or not, and compare the result.

Can't check since I'm not in front of a computer now, but I think it should work :)

Edit: While I typed my answer, some other people were quicker to type...

Comment: Won't work for matching `1` bits, and `p1` and `p2` are one-based.

Answer (score 0):

in C:

```
   #define SAMEBIT(n, p1, p2) \
       ((n >> (p1-1)) & (n >> (p2-1)) & 1)
```

in Smalltalk:

```
   (n bitAt:p1) = (n bitAt:p2)
```

in Java:

```
   like C
```

Comment: I didn't realise that java supported macros!?! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with bitmasks and the `&` (bitwise and) operator. You create two bitmasks--one for `p1` and another for `p2`--by shifting a `1` bit into the correct position using `<<` (shift left). Mask `n` with each bit mask and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

assuming 0 based on from most significant bit (i.e. sign bit is at 0)

```
boolean bitPositionsSame(int n, int p1, int p2) {
    return (n & 0x80000000>>>p1)==(n & 0x80000000>>>p2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `p1` bit of `n`:

```
(n >> (p1-1)) & 1
```

Get the `p2` bit of `n`:

```
(n >> (p2-1)) & 1
```

Compare them for equality:

```
bool result = ((n >> (p1-1))&1) == ((n >> (p2-1))&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation:

```
bool same_bits = !(n & p1 - 1) == !(n & p2 - 1);
```

Coercing the type of the result of the bitwise AND to `bool` with `!` constrains the possible values down to only `0` or `1`.